# Telerik Radgrid export file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

Does any one know how to provide `file name` to the exported file in `Telerik RadGrid`,
Exported file could be of any format pdf, excel or word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: [Grid / MS Excel/MS Word/CSV](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx)

> Use RadGrid.ExportSettings.FileName property, a string specifying the
>   name (without the extension) of the file that will be created. The
>   file extension is automatically added based on the method that is used
>   Try setting the `FileName` in the `ItemCommand` event as shown below.

From: [When to set RadGrid.ExportSettings.FileName](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/when-to-set-radgrid-exportsettings-filename.aspx)

```
protected void Radgrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExportToPdfCommandName)
    {
        Radgrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "yourfilename";
    }
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExportToExcelCommandName)
    {
        Radgrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "yourfilename";
    }
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExportToWordCommandName)
    {
        Radgrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "yourfilename";
    }
}
```

Reference:
[Export RadGrid content to Excel/Word/CSV/PDF with Ajax enabled](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/general/export-radgrid-content-to-excel-word-csv-pdf-with-ajax-enabled.aspx)

Comment: Has anybody gotten the filename property to work correctly?   It is getting ignoredby the RadGrid export when I attempt to set it.

Comment: yes me too... tried several events but it's always ignored

Answer (score 1):

You can set the filename as well as other options for exporting, on the `ExportSettings` property of the grid (not the `MasterTableView`). So for example:

```
myGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "file";
myGrid.ExportSettings.Excel.Extension = "xls";
myGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

Comment: According to the docs you should leave out the extension - "a string specifying the name (without the extension)" http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @Kevin Main I forgot that was the case indeed. Although I do think that the export function will ignore the extension if you leave it in. But I'm not able to test it now, so I'll edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
     try
     {
        object districtid = Session["DistID"];

        RadGrid tempGrid = rgDupEmpoyees;
        string fileName = "LEA_" + districtid .ToString() + "_PossibleNoShowTonySopranoEmployees_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MMM_yyyy");
        tempGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = fileName;
        tempGrid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.UseStaticHeaders = false;
        tempGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        this.LogException(ex);
        DisplayPageMessage(ex.GetBaseException().Message, PageMessageType.Error);
        //e.Cancel = true;
     }
     finally
     {
        this.LogMethodExit();
     }
```